# Sql statement for finding intervals of increase/decease

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

[image: table]

this represent the level of fuel in a tank. i need a sql statement to determine the time intervals of continuous increase and continuous decrease from the tank. In the end i want to determine when the tank is reffiled. i need a result tables with this columns: starttime,endtime,increase/decrease. 
On the increase/decrese i want the difference of the values from endtime to startime, it will be possitive if the value increases and negative if the value decreases

Comment: i'm using sql server

Comment: Please provide your data in a **consumable** format, images aren't helpful to anyone. [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)